# Matlab: Make a count-down for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, range

Is there an easy way to make a for loop count down instead of up?

I know that I can do something like this:

```
for i = 1:100
    % do stuff
end
```

But I need the numbers in the opposite order. When I do this:

```
for i = 100:1
    % do stuff
end
```

It says that 'i' is an empty matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply flip the looping variable. This has the benefit of working for any arbitrary looping variable.

```
for i = flip(1:100)
end
```

For your specific example, you could specify a negative increment value for the colon operator

```
for i = 100:-1:1
end
```